# XMLmind DITA converter outputs wrong HTML

Tags: java, html, xslt, saxon, dita

I'm currently testing the DITA converter tool (https://www.xmlmind.com/ditac/). The test I'm performing is to convert a simple DITA topic XML file to an HTML document (from Java code). To do so, I'm currently using the example provided on their website (https://www.xmlmind.com/ditac/_distrib/doc/manual/embed/Embed2.java). The DITA topic to convert looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE topic PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Topic//EN" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="docbook_or_dita">
  <title>DITA or DocBook?</title>  
  <shortdesc>Both DITA and DocBook are both mature, feature rich, document types,
    so which one to choose?</shortdesc>  
  <body>
    <p>DocBook 5 is a mature document type...</p>    
    <p>DITA concepts (topics, maps, specialization, etc)...</p>    
  </body>

  <related-links>
    <link format="html" href="http://www.docbook.org/" scope="external">
      <linktext>DocBook 5</linktext>
    </link>

    <link format="html"
      href="http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=dita"
      scope="external">
      <linktext>DITA</linktext>
    </link>
  </related-links>
</topic>
```

The results are satisfactory and I get the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta><title>DITA or DocBook?</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="res/basic.css"></link><meta name="description" content="Both DITA and DocBook are both mature, feature rich, document types, so which one to choose?"></meta>
      <meta name="generator" content="XMLmind DITA Converter 3.5.0"></meta>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="docbook_or_dita" class="topic">
         <h2 class="section1-title">DITA or DocBook?</h2>
         <p class="shortdesc">Both DITA and DocBook are both mature, feature rich, document types,
            so which one to choose?
         </p>
         <div class="body">
            <div class="p">DocBook 5 is a mature document type...</div>
            <div class="p">DITA concepts (topics, maps, specialization, etc)...</div>
         </div>
         <div class="related-links">
            <h3 class="related-links-title">Related information</h3>
            <p class="link">‣ <a href="http://www.docbook.org/" target="_blank">DocBook 5</a></p>
            <p class="link">‣ <a href="http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=dita" target="_blank">DITA</a></p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, the problem comes when I modify the original DITA file to use W3C XML schema instead of DTD (by using the DTDToSchema facility -> https://www.xmlmind.com/ditac/_distrib/doc/manual/dita_support.html). When using the W3C XML schema the DITA topic looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:dita:xsd:topic.xsd" id="docbook_or_dita">
  <title>DITA or DocBook?</title>  
  <shortdesc>Both DITA and DocBook are both mature, feature rich, document types,
    so which one to choose?</shortdesc>  
  <body>
    <p>DocBook 5 is a mature document type...</p>    
    <p>DITA concepts (topics, maps, specialization, etc)...</p>    
  </body>

  <related-links>
    <link format="html" href="http://www.docbook.org/" scope="external">
      <linktext>DocBook 5</linktext>
    </link>

    <link format="html"
      href="http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=dita"
      scope="external">
      <linktext>DITA</linktext>
    </link>
  </related-links>
</topic>
```

When trying to convert it to HTML using the `Embed2.java` I get some errors like:

- `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unexpected "topic" element` (fixed by adding `class="- topic/topic "` to the `topic` root element)
- and `missing "ditaarch:DITAArchVersion" attribute` (fixed by adding `xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.3"` again to the `topic` root element).

After fixing the previous errors, the conversion is executed without errors. However, the resulting HTML page does not contain HTML tags inside the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta><title></title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="res/basic.css"></link><meta name="generator" content="XMLmind DITA Converter 3.5.0"></meta>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="docbook_or_dita" class="topic">
         DITA or DocBook?  
         Both DITA and DocBook are both mature, feature rich, document types,
         so which one to choose?  

         DocBook 5 is a mature document type...    
         DITA concepts (topics, maps, specialization, etc)...    




         DocBook 5



         DITA



      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to generate an HTML from a DITA topic (using the Java approach) which does not reference the DTD?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So how does that schema `topic.xsd` look exactly? Any chance it declares a default namespace attribute on the elements and that way the XSLT match patterns or select expressions fail? The result you show looks a bit like that, as if some input unrelated document structure is output and then the rest is processed by the built-in templates which only copy text output, which often happens in case of namespace inconsistencies between the XML input and the XSLT.

Comment: By taking a deeper look on the process I've realized that the problem seems to be on the XMLmind converter pre-processor. This pre-processor generates an incomplete "ditac" file (the class attribute is missing on all ditac elements). So that means that the problem is not related with the XSL transformation.